# How do I limit the x and y value of a 3-d graph on gnuplot to be only integer values?

Tags: gnuplot, graphing

OK so I have plotted a 3-d graph `z = x-y*15/36` on gnuplot but I am trying to find points on this function where both the `x` and `y` values are integers I am aware that conditions can be set with the ternary operator but I cannot find any type of comparator or function that would let me set the function to only accept integer `x` and `y` values.

I have searched the help in gnuplot and found nothing and an hour search on Google did not help either. Any advice on how to solve this is appreciated, even if I have to use another graphing software.

Comment: Note that in gnuplot, `15/36` is the same as `0`.  maybe you wanted `15./36.`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I get what you're asking, but this seems to work:

```
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]
set samples 21,21
set isosamples 21,21
splot x-y*15./36. w p
```

The key is to figure out how many integers there are in your range and set samples and isosamples to that value.

To explain, `set samples` determines where gnuplot samples the function for plotting.  The syntax is `set samples NX,NY`.  In this case, I choose 21 samples, meaning sample at `x=-10,x=-9,...,x=0,...,x=9,x=10` and the same for `y`.  That just picks which "isolines are drawn.  `set isosamples` determines how many points are drawn along each line.  (again, 21, because I wanted them plotted at `x=-10,...,x=10` and the same for `y`.

Comment: if you don't mind asking could you explain the code its a bit difficult to understand how it works, but it seems to do what i wanted thank you (i would up vote but it seems i need more rep)

Comment: @psionicscv -- added some explanation.